# Delayed function within a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timeout, closures

I am logging a variable to the console as I move through a for loop, but I would like it to occur at intervals, so I am trying to use `setTimeout`.

```
function foo(val) {
    return function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(val);
        }, 2000);
    };
};

$(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        $(foo(i));
    };
});
```

The first instance works properly (it occurs after 2000 milliseconds), but the remaining iterations log the variable immediately. They don't have their own delays. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `$(foo(i));`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hboxdsb1/1/

Comment: Okay, I've looked at the question that is a duplicate of mine. While I see that I can make it work by adding to the delay each time through the loop, I don't understand why I need to. Why does each loop execute at once without the delay each time? I also looked at your fiddle, which does not work for me, until I add the JQuery $ ready method, which you said was unnecessary. I see that it's unnecessary, but it doesn't work for me without it. Sooo  confused....